# How to call StretchBlt by pressing a button? Program is not loading

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

```
case ID_BUTTON2:
    {
        StretchBlt(hdc, 100, rect.bottom, rect.right, -rect.bottom, hmem, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY); // mirror vertically

        break;
    }
```

When I call it this way or try to release DC first, program is just not running. Just not a pro of handling memory alloc if this is a problem. So what might be a solution?

and in WM_PAINT I have:

```
 case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); // Get DC handle
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);  // Get client rectangle
    hmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    hbmp = LoadImage(0, "\\image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); 
    SelectObject(hmem, hbmp);
    GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
    StretchBlt(hdc, 100, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, hmem, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

        if ((HWND)lParam == ID_BUTTON2) { // HOW TO MAKE IT WORK, I have read documentation, and googled a lot, just doesn't work

        if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {
            StretchBlt(hdc, 100, rect.bottom, rect.right, -rect.bottom, hmem, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);// mirror vertically
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: don't forget to call `EndPaint`.  Also, why are you calling `StretchBlt` outside of your `WM_PAINT` handler?

Comment: I wanted to change the bitmap like mirroring by changing destination coordinates if user pressed a button.

Comment: You should still do it in your `WM_PAINT` handler.  You can trigger a redraw by calling `InvalidateRect`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actuallyi tried to do that and for 5 hours now i stuck, can't trigger the BT_CLICKED to be a flag in WM_PAINT

Comment: defined a button `#define ID_BUTTON2 2`
inside of createWindowW I have `(HMENU)ID_BUTTON2 `
 
How to trigger a Button clicked in WM_PAINT?
i tried doing that with global variable but it just doesn't work no errors, nothing

Comment: You should call `InvalidateRect` in your `ID_BUTTON2` handler, setting a flag which can be tested in your `WM_PAINT` handler to tell it what to do.

Comment: When i declare an int `mirror = 0` and then test it in `WM_PAINT` (making it `mirror = 1` in `ID_BUTTON2` ) it doesn't evaluates it properly, also tried `BOOL mirror = FALSE` and switchig it in `ID_BUTTON2` to `mirror = TRUE`. and still it doesn't work, what might be the problem?

Comment: Please post your code as a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the button press in `WM_COMMAND`.

Here is some code you can refer to:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); // Get DC handle
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);  // Get client rectangle
    hmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    hbmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(0, L"\\image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    SelectObject(hmem, hbmp);
    GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
    StretchBlt(hdc, 100, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, hmem, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
case WM_COMMAND:
    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON2) { // HOW TO MAKE IT WORK, I have read documentation, and googled a lot, just doesn't work
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {
            StretchBlt(hdc, 100, rect.bottom, rect.right, -rect.bottom, hmem, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);// mirror vertically
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.

Comment: Hi!, thank you for your reply I almost lost hope. And yes it does work thank you  very much really appreciate it :)